# Trace Java method execution

Tags: java, spring-boot, trace, jstack

I am having a hard time finding a way to trace a method execution (ex: methods being called at execution..)

Here is the code snippet I want to trace:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
        public String test(){

            String jsonString = "{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"type\":\"Booking\",\"sid\":\"A43521\",\"region\":\"ASIA\","
                + "\"fetchFromFile\":\"false\",\"service\":\"true\",\"isEom\":\"true\",*#@!}";
            String response = JsonSanitizer.sanitize(jsonString);
            return response;
        }
```

I'd like to know that the method **sanitize** of **JsonSanitizer** class has been called ..

I tried running jstack, but I don't see any occurences of JsonSanitizer.sanitize method in the stack traces.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remote debugging? AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) - it would change the byte code.? Simplest and best remains logging.

Comment: i would suggest to write unit or integration test and verify if your objects are getting called at runtime

Comment: Thanks for the insights, but I cannot change the code in my case. I need something in jstack style

Answer (score 0):

You can either add log statements in your code, which write information to a log file or System.out for example, or you can run the application in debug mode and add a breakpoint in the code from where you want to start tracking what happens. When the code execution reaches the breakpoint, the debugger will pause execution and you can step through/in/out the statements one by one.

Comment: Thank you Adriaan, I am actually looking for a dynamic way which does not involve adding code or breakpoints to trace what happens inside the execution ( methods being called .. )

Comment: For further ideas you could look towards coverage tools like Cobertura and Jacoco which  use byte code instrumentation to keep track of executed code. Or you could think about an AOP solution to intercept method calls in the part of the code you are interested in (e.g. AspectJ).